# How to not minify js file in build in gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gulp

I want to NOT minify the main js file ( app.js ) in production mode ( npm run build ). I use **webpack-stream** to compress and import various files/libraries into one single app.js file. But, for some reason, I need a regular readable js file as in development, with files imported into it, but without compression, how can I do that?

**JS.JS:**

```
import webpack from "webpack-stream";

export const js = () => {
  return app.gulp.src(app.path.src.js, { sourcemaps: app.isDev })
    .pipe(app.plugins.plumber(
      app.plugins.notify.onError({
        title: "JS",
        message: "Error: <%= error.message %>"
      }))
    )
    .pipe(webpack({
      mode: app.isBuild ? 'production' : 'development',
      output: {
        filename: 'app.min.js',
      }
    }))
    .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.js))
    .pipe(app.plugins.browsersync.stream());
}
```

**JS.JS ( After some changes ):**

```
import webpack from "webpack-stream";

export const js = () => {
    return app.gulp.src(app.path.src.js, { sourcemaps: app.isDev })
        .pipe(app.plugins.plumber(
            app.plugins.notify.onError({
                title: "JS",
                message: "Error: <%= error.message %>"
            }))
        )
        .pipe(webpack({
            mode: 'development',
            optimization: {
                minimize: false
            },
            output: {
                filename: 'app.js',
            },
            resolve: {
                modules: [
                    'node_modules'
                ]
            },
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                        test: /\.js/,
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
                    }
                ]
            }
        }))
        .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.js))
        .pipe(app.plugins.browsersync.stream());
}
```

**APP.JS:**

```
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    "use strict";
/******/    var __webpack_modules__ = ({

/***/ "./src/js/app.js":
/*!***********************!*\
  !*** ./src/js/app.js ***!
  \***********************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack___webpack_module__, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__); ...
```

I tried setting webpack not to compress the file using **optimization**, changed **mode** to only development mode, and added modules: **babel-loader**, but nothing worked.

I don’t know how to solve it, if you need more information, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about webpack-stream,
but in these cases I use [gulp-if](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if).

[gulp-if](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if) becomes very handy when you generate both beautified and minified versions of file.js **together**.

the code then looks something like this =>

```
  // destination for the output if dev-env or in prod-env before minification
  .pipe(dest(outputDir))

  // minifying our js file/s only if in production environment
  .pipe(
    gulpIf(
      isProd,
      minifyJs({
        ext: {
          src: ".js",
          min: ".js",
        },
        mangle: false,
        noSource: true,
        ignoreFiles: [".combo.js", ".min.js"],
      })
    )
  )

  // destination for the output if prod-env after minification
  .pipe(gulpIf(isProd, dest(outputDir)))
```

notice the **isProd** variable.

for more, please find this [gulp-boilerplate](https://github.com/Mohamed-Talaat333/gulp-boilerplate) for your assist.